# input type number as dropdown

Tags: php, numbers, dropdown

i have this following code:

```
<?php extract( $field ); ?>
<p class="form-field form-field-wide <?php echo implode( ' ', $class ); ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $label ); ?>:</label>
    <input
        class="number"
        type="number"
        value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $min ) ) ? $min : 0; ?>"
        step="<?php echo ( isset( $step ) ) ? $step : ''; ?>"
        min="<?php echo ( isset( $min ) ) ? $min : ''; ?>"
        max="<?php echo ( isset( $max ) ) ? $max : ''; ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>"
        /> <span class="after_text"><?php echo ( ! empty( $after ) ) ? $after : ''; ?></span>
</p>
```

better than the input as a number is a dropdown for us.
Is there a option to get a dropdown from min to max.

Do you have any ideas how I can handle this?

best regards

Comment: A "dropdown" is known as a `select` element in HTML, within which you will have to construct an `option` for each value that you want present in the dropdown. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: I know, but how can I get a option from min to max?

Comment: `Option` elements display one discrete value within the `select` element as a whole. So again, you need an `option` element for each discrete value in the range you want to represent. You can make each `option` programmatically with PHP by looping  from `$min` to `$max` and making an `option` element for each value.

Comment: big thanks - that works for me.